Am i Jewish or am I a gentile
My father is Jewish and mother is Christian. I was raised Jewish. Taken to temple and had my bar mitzvah. Recently I was told by another Jewish person I am not Jewish because of my mother. I am interested in your prospective ty Rabbi

Hi Joshua and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Your question is an important question about your personal self, and therefore is not covered by the policy of this website. You can find resources here already about what makes a Jew a Jew, but you ultimately should find an orthodox Rabbi to talk to directly. This is the only sensible way to get the right answer to your question, regardless of our policy. Either way, please don't take it as a sign that we are not concerned when this question gets closed due to the aforementioned policy. Wishing you the best and hope to hear from you in future. All the best

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_is_a_Jew%3F

@Shalom I’d be wary of any Wikipedia page relating to culture, especially Judaism. The site’s extremely biased.

The point's simple enough. Halachic Judaism says Jewish status follows the mother. Other denominations (especially those with "temples" rather than "synagogues") are okay with "any Jewish parent, plus Jewish identification/affiliation." So that's what's going on here.
